# Is there a way to store a static pointer address in an enumeration in C++

Tags: c++

This might not be possible in C++, but I am not sure why. I have been searching stack overflow and google but I'm unable to find an answer.

First I will state the assumptions I'm working off of.

First Assumption: If I have this code at a global scope. I would expect it to be stored in the Data segment of the program which means at compile time the memory address is known.
`char const* const test1 = "test1";`

Second Assumption: Enum values are stored as symbols in the symbol table.

This code compiles:

```
enum class test : size_t
{
    TEST0 = 123,
    TEST1 = 456
};
```

However, given that size_t is 32 bits on a 32 bit machine and 64 bits on a 64 bit machine, I should be able to store a pointer's address. However, this will not compile.

```
char const* const test1 = "test1";

enum class test : size_t
{
    TEST0 = 123,
    TEST1 = (size_t)test1
};
```

Why does this not work? test1's address should be known at compile time and it should simply be saving the memory address.

The goal of doing this is that I would be able to convert the address back into a pointer and use it to convert my enum into a character array (ie: string).

Comment: The address won't be fixed until link time (at best).

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 The error message is unimportant here.

Comment: @Sneftel it isnt essential I agree, but unimportant it is not imho. Nevermind, the question is completely fine as it stands.

Comment: I would note that `size_t` may not be large enough to store a pointer. You should use: `intptr_t` which is an integer type guaranteed to be large enough to hold a normal pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test1`'s address is not known at compile time (things like address space layout randomization affect it), and it *certainly* isn't known while compiling (because variables aren't laid out together in the data segment until linking).

Your question really sounds like an XY problem. If you have a bunch of unique `char*`s, why stuff them into an enum? They already represent an enumeration.

Comment: It sounds like OP wants an array of variables. Either that or OP is in embedded and is trying to apply the usual fixed-address hardware registers code style to normal variables.

Comment: Ah yes, the linker and address space layout randomization. I forgot about that. Mainly I was trying to achieve an easy way to flip an enum into a character array and possibly vice versa. I thought of Assembly and that I would do it with `db 'test1'` and then just save that address.

Comment: @Acorn Actually not in embedded, but I was trying to do something like `TEST1 db 'test1'` (asm) and then use enum as a fancy container. Addresses are unique so.... essentially enumerating the addresses. But with the ability to cast that address back into a const char*.

Comment: @Questionable While you cannot know the exact address, you can know some offsets, like those of members in a structure. Put all variables in it and then combine the offsets with the base and there you go.

Comment: @Acorn Yes, I can see storing things in a struct to get the offsets. How would I get the base? It sounds like this would be a runtime operation?

Comment: @Questionable Yes, of course, the base would be a runtime value; but the offsets wouldn't.

Comment: @Acorn Ok. This is worth a try. Even if it doesn't do exactly what I want I can still say I learned something that might be exactly what I need in the future.